# Помогите перевести SQL-query в Elasticsearch-query

Tags: sql, запрос, elasticsearch

Помогите перевести sql-выражение в запрос для Elasticsearch(v6.x):

```
select IndexA.* from IndexA where IndexA.NAME like ('%stics%') and IndexA.ID in (1,2,3,4)
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно - так:

```
POST /IndexA/_search -d '
{
 "query" : {
  "bool" : { 
    "must" : [
        {
            "wildcard" : {
                    "name" : "*stics*"
            } 
        },
        { 
            "terms" : {
                "_id" : ["1", "2", "3"] 
            }
        }
    ]
  }
 }
}'
```